# How can I read Uri , double values from json file in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Car class and it has brand name , price and uri for image. I have a recyler view in my main activity. I can store my brand name and my other strings in json file and show all strings in recyler view but how can I store and read uri and double in json file?

**NewCar**

```
        var newCar = Car()



        newCar.brandName = brandName.text.toString()
        newCar.modelName = modelName.text.toString()

        newCar.price = price.text.toString().toDouble()

        newCar.fuelType = fuelType.text.toString()
        newCar.gearType = gearType.text.toString()
        newCar.km = kilometer.text.toString().toDouble()
        newCar.image = imageUri


        val callingActivity = activity as MainActivity?
        callingActivity!!.createNewCar(newCar)
```

**JSON Constructor**

```
@Throws(JSONException::class)
constructor(jo: JSONObject) {

    modelName = jo.getString(JSON_MODELNAME)
    brandName = jo.getString(JSON_BRANDNAME)
    fuelType = jo.getString(JSON_FUELTYPE)
    km = jo.getDouble(JSON_KM)
    price = jo.getDouble(JSON_PRICE)
    color = jo.getString(JSON_COLOR)
   
    gearType = jo.getString(JSON_GEARTYPE)
    
    image = jo.get // what should I write here

}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Store `uri` as `String`:

```
newCar.image = imageUri.toString()

image = jo.getString(xxx)
```